# JsonObject breaks with new Dart libs?

Tags: dart

It looks like the new Dart libraries from this morning are breaking the JsonObject lib.
When running existing code the output I get is:

```
Exception: NoSuchMethodError : method not found: 'JSON'
Receiver: Type: class 'JsonObject'
```

How to resolve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the JSON library now has `stringify` and `parse` as top-level objects.

I've update [JsonOjbect](https://github.com/chrisbu/dartwatch-JsonObject) to work with the latest version of the editor (17328).

Unfortunately, this also means I've had to remove the `objectToJson` top-level function, which needs some work to get it working with the new future syntax.

Try `pub update` to pull in the latest version.

Comment: That's the second time an issue with JsonObject was 'mysteriously' resolved by running pub update. Thanks again for the quick response!

Comment: No problem.  This is like a "crowd-sourced" TODO list for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, deleting pubspec.lock and running pub update resolved the issue. Must be related than to the update release of the Dart Editor (version 0.3.1_r17328).

Comment: Obviously the answer Chris provided above is the correct answer. Our answers were not far apart in time and I didn't see his post while posting my own answer. Doh!